# HTML5 Boilerplate ant build subdirectory

Tags: html5boilerplate, antbuilder

I have config in project .properties

```
file.pages        =dashboard/**/*.html
```

in dashboard/index.html i have

```
<!-- //-beg- concat_js -->
<script src="../js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="../js/base64.js"></script>
<script src="../js/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.h5validate.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<!-- //-end- concat_js -->
```

But I am getting the build output as

```
 <script src="js/c1212c4.js"></script>
```

but file is generated in

```
../js/c1212c4.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two separate script directories that don't have a child/parent relationship (`js/vendor`, for example). You can configure it to work that way by editing the `build.xml`, but we didn't design it to do so out of the box. It's basically because the regular expression that does the replace captures the directory based on the path to `script.js` in the source but other operations can be based on `dir.js` (which is what I'm assuming is happening here) or other operations (the concatenation, for example, just follows file system links to pull in the files to concatenate.) Basing the build script on a default h5bp install (one `js` directory with children), we're covered, but with this configuration it's not straightforward.

To solve your problem, pick one directory or edit the `build.xml` to point to your output directory.

Comment: I actually tried make two seperate buld.xml , publishing a same directory, that even didnt worked.

Comment: ../js/jquery.maskedinput.js  gives 404 on subdirectory build

Comment: You wouldn't want to make two separate build.xml. That doesn't make any sense. These problems are just path based. You can point Ant anywhere you want it to go. That said, it would be MUCH easier if you just had one js directory. Is there some reason you have two? That's the way it's designed and wouldn't have you messing around with Ant.

Comment: The reason is simple. Parent for nonlogged in users, and dashboard directory for logged in users. As there is no point to load logged in user js for non-logged in, so they both have seperate js/css directories.

Comment: Then you really want to look at doing some custom work. We built the build script for a default h5bp project. The configuration options can only go so far and you're well outside what we're offering based on just configuration options.